# Passing on TLS credentials

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, webservice-client

I have a SOAP WS called with client authentication and I need to pass on the client certificate that was received to another Web Service. How can I do that?

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "test")
public List<String> test() {
    // Do some stuff
    // Call another Web Service which needs to authenticate the client too
}
```